# Fail to get iptables to forward correctly on SuSE Linux

Tags: iptables, opensuse, sles

I am struggling to forward a port via `iptables`. I did a lot of googling but all solutions I tried do not work.

Very simple setup with three computers on the same LAN

```
192.168.0.1 # destination
192.168.0.2 # redirector (only one interface)
192.168.0.3 # source
```

My `iptables` config is pretty simple as well

```
# iptables -L -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:192.168.0.1
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 to:192.168.0.1

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination 

# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

According to what I read this should work. But it doesn't. I alternatively played with `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -p tcp -d 192.168.0.1 --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1` but doesn't work either. And yes `ip_forward` is enabled.

Browsing to `192.168.0.2:80/443` should return content from `192.168.0.1`, no? Any ideas?

Comment: You need a masquerade rule, and the interface that is connected to your WAN. The box that will be the router needs 2 interfaces. Something like this: /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state
   --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

Comment: So it cannot work on a host with a single interface?

Comment: I got it working! The correct rules are `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.2 ! -s 192.168.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:80` and `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to 192.168.0.2`. Adding `-d` did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! The correct rules are

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.2 ! -s 192.168.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to 192.168.0.2.
```

Adding -d did the trick.